# how to do Event-Arc configuration through code?

Tags: configuration, event-arc

I am trying to configure event arc using node.js code. any idea on how Event-Arc configuration can be done with node.js.

Answer (score 0):

Because there is a lot of lacking information in your question I will have to do some assumptions.

If you want to set up Eventarc, there is a client library for NodeJS available [here](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/eventarc/latest).

Depending on your use case you either want to read about

- Triggers that are listening for Google source  ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/targets))
- Third party integrations ([docs](https://cloud.google.com/eventarc/docs/third-parties/third-parties-overview))
- Custom events integration via Firebase ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta/custom-events))